# Why does my cat scratch around water before drinking it?

Tags: cats, behavior, drinking

My cat likes to scratch at the edges of any and all kinds of water bowls and then tenses up when he drinks the water. I've tried all kinds of different water bowls but he scratches at all of them so hard that he just flips them over and spills water everywhere. I've even tried the colored plastic ice cubes so he can see the water level easier. It's to the point that I can't even have a glass of water for myself because he spills it trying to paw at it so hard.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with my cat although it's not to that extent. My cat would sometimes dig for like a second then drink or eat normally out of the bowls. My mother believes that our cat is doing it to 'save up' some food for later which is apparently normal in outdoors conditions.

Comment: Has your cat ever shown a preference for MOVING water? Like an indoor-fountain, or a running faucet? Perhaps your cat just prefer the water running. Check his reaction to faucets!

Comment: I had an electric water fountain thing and he just tipped it over like the rest :b I also got one of those tall ones that store lots of water so it's never empty and THAT was a huge mistake. so much water everywhere. but I'll try just leaving my bathroom sink on.

Comment: I seem to recall this exact question being asked a few months ago, but I can't find it.